# Display uiview with dynamic height based upon content using NSLayoutConstraints programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am working on view which will have a label and few buttons. The length of view should depend upon the text in label. I have tried to place label and button in the view vertically and add constraints but label does not display at all. I am sure I am making some mistakes in adding the constraints. Can someone please help me?
My code:

```
    ssrsMessageView = UIView()
        ssrsMessageView.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(ssrsMessageView)
        
        ssrsMessageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
        ssrsMessageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        ssrsMessageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        ssrsMessageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
//        ssrsMessageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
        
        closeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: screenWidth-85, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30))
        closeButton.setImage(R.image.closeIcon()?.tint(R.color.darkRedColor().expect()), for: .normal)
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dissmissViewController), for: .touchUpInside)
        ssrsMessageView.addSubview(closeButton)
        
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = R.color.virginRed()
        button.setTitle(R.string.localizable.moreInfo(), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dissmissViewController), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.titleLabel?.font = R.font.montserratBold(size: 16)
        ssrsMessageView.addSubview(button)

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let marginsMessageView = ssrsMessageView.layoutMarginsGuide
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
        
        let lblMessage = UILabel()
        lblMessage.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. "
        lblMessage.textColor = .green
        lblMessage.numberOfLines = 0
        lblMessage.font = R.font.montserratRegular(size: 14)
        ssrsMessageView.addSubview(lblMessage)
        ssrsMessageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        lblMessage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        lblMessage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        lblMessage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        lblMessage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can share the screenshot of the expected UI.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is that you're trying to set the **bottom** of the label 10-pts from the **top** of the button, but you used `10` for the constant when it should be `-10`.

You will probably find doing this much easier by grouping related tasks together, such as:

- create and configure views
- add them to the view hierarchy
- set constraints in order

You'll also find it helps to write comments describing what you expect the constraints to do... makes it much easier to find mistakes.

Take a look at this approach:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var ssrsMessageView: UIView!
    var closeButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // setup the views
        ssrsMessageView = UIView()
        ssrsMessageView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        closeButton = UIButton()
        closeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "aaa"), for: .normal)

        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .red // R.color.virginRed()
        button.setTitle("More Info", for: .normal)

        let lblMessage = UILabel()
        lblMessage.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet."
        lblMessage.textColor = .green
        lblMessage.numberOfLines = 0
        
        // let's give the label a background color so we can see its frame
        lblMessage.backgroundColor = .brown

        // view hierarchy
        view.addSubview(ssrsMessageView)

        ssrsMessageView.addSubview(closeButton)
        ssrsMessageView.addSubview(button)
        ssrsMessageView.addSubview(lblMessage)

        // we want to use autolayout constraints
        ssrsMessageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        closeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lblMessage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // use safe area guide for subviews of the main view
        let margins = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let marginsMessageView = ssrsMessageView.layoutMarginsGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain ssrsMessageView at bottom
            ssrsMessageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor),
            ssrsMessageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor),
            ssrsMessageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor),
            
            // constrain closeButton at top-right of ssrsMessageView, 30x30
            closeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            closeButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            closeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
            closeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: closeButton.widthAnchor),

            // constrain button
            //  bottom to ssrsMessageView bottom margin guide minus 10-pts "padding"
            //  leading / trailing to ssrsMessageView margin guide with 20-pts "padding"
            //  Height: 50-pts
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0),
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            
            // constrain lblMessage
            //  top to ssrsMessageView top margin guide plus 10-pts "padding"
            //  leading / trailing to ssrsMessageView margin guide with 20-pts "padding"
            //  bottom to button top plus 10-pts "padding"
            lblMessage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.topAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            lblMessage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            lblMessage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginsMessageView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            lblMessage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor, constant: -10.0),

        ])
    }
}
```